# Depth vs Distance in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: tree, distance, binary-search-tree, depth

Is the depth of a node in a Binary Search Tree (BST) the same as it's distance from the root?  I think so, but I'm not certain.  I believe distance is the concept of trees in general and depth is that concept applied to BSTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, depth = distance from root. From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree):

> The depth of a node n is the length of the path from the root to the node.